# My Tcl expect script on Centos 5.5 or 8.2 tries to ssh to a Windows 10 machine and connects but can't reliably get output

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a Tcl script that uses Expect on a CentOS 5.5 (old legacy work environment) or a CentOS 8.2 machine that opens an SSH session to a Windows 10 machine.  I'm able to successfully connect but the data I get from $expect_out(buffer) is not correct.  I seem to just get snippets of the output I expect as well as some unexpected characters that seem to move the output around the screen.  When I watch in putty as the script runs, after the password is input the putty screen is cleared and "Microsoft Windows..." is in the first line of the window indicating the start of the ssh session.  Then I can follow the commands I expect and the output on the screen looks good but it stops once it gets to the bottom of the putty window.  Then my "puts" of the data after exiting the ssh session seem to just get overlayed on the data that was already in the putty window and my prompt and cursor will be in the middle of the output.  Does Windows send back screen location type characters or anything that will screw up my data that I need to parse out?  This behavior is identical on two different Windows 10 machines.  Manually doing this from the command line works fine.

Centos 5.5, tcl 8.5, expect 5.43.0

Centos 8.2.2004, tcl 8.6, expect 5.45.4

My script just gets "netsh wlan show int", "ipconfig" and "dir".  This is the output on the screen as all output is confined to the screen...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139] (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

dell-lat-7300@SR3-DELL-AX C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300>
===========end ipconfig data 2=============

Hosted network status: Not available

==========start dir data 3===================
DELL-LAT-7300>ipconfig ipconfig

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : ip   
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ip
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ip
                                       ip
 
Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

dell-lat-7300@SR3-DELL-AX C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300>
===========end dir data 3============= Media disconnected    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

[user@pc-hawk ~]$  wlan0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : ip   
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ip 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : ip 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ip
                                       ip

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

dell-lat-7300@SR3-DELL-AX C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300>dir  
Volume in drive C is OS  Volume Serial Number is 4C91-A066

 Directory of C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300

06/21/2020  09:23 PM    <DIR>          . 06/21/2020  09:23 PM    <DIR>
09/16/2019  10:31 AM    <DIR>          .idlerc

==========start netsh data 1============== netsh wlan show int
```

My Tcl Expect script:

```
package require Expect
set client_ip "10.10.10.203"
set username "username"
set password "password"
set rawdata1 ""
set rawdata2 ""
set rawdata3 ""
set rawdata4 ""
set timeout 10
spawn ssh $client_ip -l $username
expect {
    timeout {
        expect *;
        exit;
    }
    -nocase "(yes/no)?" {
        after 500
        exp_send "yes\r\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    -nocase "password:" {
        after 500
        exp_send "$password\r\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    -nocase ">" { }
}
catch {expect ">"}
catch {expect *}
set rawdata1 ""
after 2000
exp_send "netsh wlan show int\r\n"
expect {
    timeout   { }
    -re ">" { }
}
set rawdata1 $expect_out(buffer)
catch {expect ">"}
catch {expect *}
after 2000
exp_send "ipconfig\r\n"
expect {
    timeout   { }
    -re ">" { }
}
set rawdata2 $expect_out(buffer)
catch {expect ">"}
catch {expect ">"}
catch {expect *}
after 2000
exp_send "dir\r\n"
expect {
    timeout   { }
    -re ">" { }
}
set rawdata3 $expect_out(buffer)
catch {expect ">"}
catch {expect ">"}
catch {expect ">"}
catch {expect *}
after 2000
exp_send "exit\r\n"
puts "\n\n==========start netsh data 1==============\n$rawdata1\n===========end netsh data 1=============\n\n"
puts "\n\n==========start ipconfig data 2==============\n$rawdata2\n===========end ipconfig data 2=============\n\n"
puts "\n\n==========start dir data 3==============\n$rawdata3\n===========end dir data 3=============\n\n"
exit
```

Based on feedback, from the output of od -c and expect -d I see a number of Escape chars (033 or 0x1b) followed by ] and then an assortment of characters. I suspect this is why my output is all over the screen. But the output of expect -d makes it look like I get a bunch of these escaped characters instead of my valid data. Even if I can clear out these characters it doesn't even look like my data is there.  Any suggestions on how to get valid data out of the Win10?

I expect this from "netsh wlan show int"
There is 1 interface on the system:

```
Name                   : wlan0
Description            : Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
GUID                   : 
Physical address       : mac
State                  : disconnected
Radio status           : Hardware On
                         Software On

Hosted network status  : Not available
```

snippet from expect -d where I send "netsh wlan show int\r"

> expect: does "
> \r\n\u001b[2J\u001b[?25l\u001b[m\u001b[H\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nr\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nr\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\u001b[H\u001b]0;c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\u0007\u001b[?25h\u001b[?25lMicrosoft
> Windows [Version 10.0.8363.1198]\u001b[18X\u001b[18C\r\n(c) 2019
> Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.\u001b[9X\u001b[9C\r\n\u001b[61X\u001b[61C\r\ndell-lat-7300@SR3-DELL-AX
> C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300>\u001b]0;Administrator:
> c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\u0007\u001b[?25h" (spawn_id exp6) match
> glob pattern "(yes/no)?"? no "password:"? no "7300>"? yes expect: set
> expect_out(0,string) "7300>" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
> expect: set expect_out(buffer) "
> \r\n\u001b[2J\u001b[?25l\u001b[m\u001b[H\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\rn\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\rn\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\u001b[H\u001b]0;c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\u0007\u001b[?25h\u001b[?25lMicrosoft
> Windws [Version 10.0.18363.1198]\u001b[18X\u001b[18C\r\n(c) 2019
> Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.\u001b[9X\u001b[9C\r\n\u001b[61X\u001b[61C\r\ndell-lat-7300@SR3-DELL-X
> C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300>" send: sending "netsh wlan show int\r" to {
> exp6 }
>
> expect: does "\u001b]0;Administrator:
> c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\u0007\u001b[?25h" (spawn_id exp6) match
> regular expression "7300>"? no
>
> expect: does "\u001b]0;Administrator:
> c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\u0007\u001b[?25h\u001b[?25lnetsh wlan show
> int\r\n\u001b[?25h" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "7300>"?
> o
>
> expect: does "\u001b]0;Administrator:
> c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\u0007\u001b[?25h\u001b[?25lnetsh wlan show
> int\r\n\u001b[?25h\u001b[?25l\u001b[HMicrosoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.1363.1198]\u001b[137X\u001b[137C\r\n(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.\u001b[128X\u001b[128C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\ndell-lat-7300@SR3-DELL-AX
> C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300>netsh wlan show
> int\u001b[100X\u001b[100C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[10X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u00b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u01b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\nu001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\rn\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180Cr\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[18C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[80C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u01b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\u001b[5;1H\u001b]0;Administrator:
> c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe - ntsh  wlan show int\u0007\u001b[?25h"
> (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "7300>"? yes expect: set
> expect_out(0,string) "7300>" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
> expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\u001b]0;Administrator:
> c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\u0007\u001b[?25h\u001b[?25lnetsh wlan show
> int\r\n\u001b[?25h\u001b[?25l\u001b[HMicrosoft Windos [Version
> 10.0.18363.1198]\u001b[137X\u001b[137C\r\n(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.\u001b[128X\u001b[128C\r\n\u001b[180X\u001b[180C\r\ndell-lat-7300@SR-DELL-AX
> C:\Users\DELL-LAT-7300>"

od -c win10_ssh.log

> 0000000  \n  \n   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   s   t   a  r

> 0000020   t       n   e   t   s   h       d   a   t   a       1   =  =

> 0000040   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =  \n 033   [  ?

> 0000060   2   5   l   n   e   t   s   h       w   l   a   n       s  h

> 0000100   o   w       i   n   t  \r  \n 033   [   ?   2   5   h 033  [

> 0000120   ?   2   5   l 033   [   H   M   i   c   r   o   s   o   f  t

> 0000140       W   i   n   d   o   w   s       [   V   e   r   s   i  o

> 0000160   n       1   0   .   0   .   1   8   3   6   3   .   1   1  9

> 0000200   8   ] 033   [   1   3   7   X 033   [   1   3   7   C  \r  \n

...

Comment: If printing to the screen is less than illuminating w.r.t to control characters, try printing to a file and inspect the file with `od -c`

Comment: Also, using `expect -d` will show very verbose debugging output that may be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand your use of multiple `catch {expect ">"}` -- I don't think `expect` errors.

Comment: To allow the connection to gracefully close, after you `send "exit\r"`, do `expect eof`

Comment: You only need to send `\r` -- that simulates "hitting Enter"